# Install FreeBSD on xhyve

Tags: virtualization

I want to install FreeBSD 10.3 as a virtual machine on my Mac mini with 10.11 via xhyve. I found this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/tanb/f8fefa22332edc7a641d). But I don't get it to install. When I run the install script I get this error.

```
dlopen(/Library/Caches/Homebrew/xhyve--git/test/userboot.so, 4): image not found
```

What do I do wrong? Also, maybe someone can explain to me, what the install script xhyverun-fbsdinstall.sh actually does.

Comment: Just curious, why xhyve when VirtualBox is so much easier?

Comment: I just to want look into it. Can't tell you more than you can lookup at xhyve.org

Comment: The hypervisor framework in OS X is a [user oriented, *lightweight* hypervisor](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251757/parallels-12-hypervisor-parallels-or-apple/259376#259376) meant for testing apps; this is the hypervisor that xhyve uses.  Personally, I think you going to expend a lot of energy trying to make something work on weak platform to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial has an error. It refers to the `userboot.so` file in the Homebrew source code cache, which may not be in the same place or existent on all systems with `xhyve` installed.

A [recent pull request](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/6681) into homebrew-core fixed this issue; that file is now in `$(brew --prefix xhyve)/share/xhyve/test/userboot.so`.

You should do the tutorial as before, but with every line starting with `USERBOOT=`