# Installing Ubuntu Virtual Machine on macOS using Native Hypervisor?

Tags: macos, virtualization, docker

I have Mac Book Pro running macOS High Sierra (10.13.5). I want to run Ubuntu in a virtual machine so that I can ultimately run it as a Kubernetes node.

I realise I could use a Type-2 / Hosted Hypervisor such as Virtual Box to do this. I was just wondering if there was a Type-1 / Native one I could use for OS X? In other words what is the Hyper-V equivalent for OS X? And is this possible or do I just use Virtual Box and be done with it?

Comment: If you need to run only one application with Ubuntu, I recommend using Docker.

Comment: See this related answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259376/119271  Personally, I would go with VirtualBox.

Comment: @pixelomer I plan to run the Ubuntu VM as a kubernetes node into an already running cluster. So yes Docker is part of the solution but largely I want to eke out as much k8s performance from inside the VM.

Comment: There are [two types of hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor#Classification), but there's no clear distinction. Try xhyve it is used to run linux for docker on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to run an Ubuntu virtual machine on macOS is probably to use [multipass](https://multipass.run/).

> Multipass can launch and run virtual machines and configure them with cloud-init like a public cloud.

Launching the current Ubuntu LTS is as easy as

```
multipass launch --name foo
```

Multipass is based on [HyperKit](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit) (a toolkit for embedding hypervisor capabilities in applications) which is itself based on [xhyve](https://github.com/machyve/xhyve) (a port of the BSD [bhyve](https://bhyve.org/) hypervisor to macOS) which itself use the [Apple Hypervisor framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/hypervisor).

Technically all these hypervisors are type 2 because they run on macOS contrary to type 1 hypervisors which would run on bare metal.