# HyperKit - Docker Desktop for Mac - Is it possible to launch traditional Debian VMs?

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

Docker for Mac currently uses HyperKit (reference: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/)

> Docker Desktop uses HyperKit instead of Virtual Box. Hyperkit is a
> lightweight macOS virtualization solution built on top of
> Hypervisor.framework in macOS 10.10 Yosemite and higher.

Is it possible to run a traditional Debian/Ubuntu VM using HyperKit on a macOS 10.15.5 or newer?

Answer (score 2):

## Multipass

It is now possible to launch an Ubuntu instance on MacOS (with HyperKit). Use Canonical's [Multipass](https://multipass.run/).

> Multipass is a mini-cloud on your workstation using native hypervisors of all the supported plaforms (Windows, macOS and Linux)

`multipass` allows you to quickly startup an Ubuntu instance on MacOS much like Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely.

I [wrote an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259376/119271) to a similar question that addressed the topic of using a a full blown hypervisor versus the framework that's built into macOS.

The framework fits Docker's model which was best described (can't remember who said it to me) as "single function blocks" and that model works perfectly with Apple's hypervisor's framework - a small, single function VM.

To get Debian going in a VM, your best bet would be to run it in a proper Hypervisor.